# SpringMVC session managament

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a simple SpringMVC v3.2.2 controller that does the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(WebRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("myattr", "myvalue", SCOPE_SESSION);
}
```

I'm using the WebRequest object in order to save attributes in the session scope. The SCOPE_SESSION is an integer stating that I want to use it in the session scope. More info on the API is here:
[WebRequest API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html)

I assume that it means that I'm adding some attribute that will be saved in the session scope. Session, I assume, will be deleted when the server restarts, during my tests, because I don't want to have any session persisted locally. Unless some default configuration keeps it persisted.

For some reason, the session doesn't get deleted even after tomcat restart(I'm using Tomcat V7, default configuration), meaning that it is persisted for some reason. Tried to find more documentation explaining how to disable it, but could not.

What Am I missing ? if the attribute is saved in the session scope, as the API states, should it get deleted if I restart the Tomcat Server ?

Thanks in advance,
Elad.
I have edited the original question, which was not so clear. Sorry.

Comment: What type is that `request` object?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You're talking about using request attributes and then complaining about the session never ending... Where exactly are you interacting with the session ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I totally missed that the session management is controlled by Tomcat.
The solution was to edit the Tomcat 7 context.xml configuration file and make sure it has the following element :

This disables the session persistence for good. Didn't really think that this is how it works by default. Thank you anyway.